# How to stay on the current sheet once I click a button that Hides and Unhides sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button()
If Range("B8") = "SBEA" Then
    Sheets("SBEA - DataEntry").Visible = Not Sheets("SBEA - DataEntry").Visible
    Sheets("SBEA - CSV").Visible = Not Sheets("SBEA - CSV").Visible
    Sheets("SBEA - Existing Equipment").Visible = Not Sheets("SBEA - Existing Equipment").Visible
Else
If Range("B8") = "EO" Then
    Sheets("Amplify - Spaces").Visible = Not Sheets("Amplify - Spaces").Visible
    Sheets("Amplify - Measures").Visible = Not Sheets("Amplify - Measures").Visible
    Sheets("Amplify - Controls").Visible = Not Sheets("Amplify - Controls").Visible
Else
If Range("B8") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please select Project Type in Cell B8"
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

In the code above, it works well hiding and unhiding the sheets selects based on the value in Cell B8. The main problem is that this code take me to the sheets that I am opening up and is not keeping me on the current sheet where the button is.

On a side not, i would like to have this change based on what is in Cell B8. Would I have to code in a list box and link into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unhiding a worksheet will also activate it.

```vb
Sub Button()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' store ActiveSheet in a variable
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    If Range("B8") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select Project Type in Cell B8"
    ElseIf Range("B8") = "SBEA" Then
        Sheets("SBEA - DataEntry").Visible = Not Sheets("SBEA - DataEntry").Visible
        Sheets("SBEA - CSV").Visible = Not Sheets("SBEA - CSV").Visible
        Sheets("SBEA - Existing Equipment").Visible = Not Sheets("SBEA - Existing Equipment").Visible
    ElseIf Range("B8") = "EO" Then
        Sheets("Amplify - Spaces").Visible = Not Sheets("Amplify - Spaces").Visible
        Sheets("Amplify - Measures").Visible = Not Sheets("Amplify - Measures").Visible
        Sheets("Amplify - Controls").Visible = Not Sheets("Amplify - Controls").Visible
    End If
    ' restore ActiveSheet if needed
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> sht.Name Then sht.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```